# Get full src of script tag that contains specific word in SRC itself

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to building chrome extensions and started with one small project where i need to print the "version of build" in a popup window. Build version is getting appended to the JS/CSS assets like below:

```
<script src="/custom/header.js?v=6.0.7159.1"></script>
```

Need to extract "6.0" from the script src value. Can you help me out how can i achieve this by traversing/searching the DOM tree?

As fas as i read in the blogs, we generally use document.queryselector or document.evaluate to  extract particular information from the currect page/tab.

Please suggest if i am not on the right path.

Comment: Are you able to add an ID to the script tag?

Comment: no, website is already live so it's not possible to add anything.

Comment: is it always going to be header.js?v=number?

Comment: Yes, this pattern will always remain same

Comment: and you have access to the script src value?

Comment: nopes, i do not have access to the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var tag = document.querySelector('script[src*="header.js"]');
var version= script.src.match(/(?:\?|&)v=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/)[1];
```

Comment: It works like a charm and also helped me as a pointer to resolve few of other queries. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the src value, then:

```
var a ='/custom/header.js?v=6.0.7159.1';
var result = a.replace(/[^\?]+\?v=(\d+\.\d+).*/i, "$1");
alert(result); //6.0
```

Comment: this is useful, but i also need to capture that particular script which contains "header.js". I am getting array of scripts with document.scripts.